# How can I always get the same column size? (Bootstrap)

Tags: c#, html, css, bootstrap-4, razor-pages

I'm building a website but I have an issue that I can't fix. I have multiple card with information inside that are in columns and each 4 columns, they switch to another row. The problem is that the number of card can change and it's not always divisible by 4. So at the end, I can have less than 4 columns in a row. And when I have les than 4 columns in a row, the displaying is not the same that when I have 4 columns in a row. I know that it's doing that because I use `col-sm` bootstrap class. It's the only way that I found that is simply responsive. I also tried to use `col-sm-3` but the problem is that the website is no more responsive. (See screenshots) By the ways, I use razor views so I can write C# and HTML.

What the displaying do when I use `col-sm`: [Display col-sm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaiPc.jpg)

The displaying that I want: [Display col-sm-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVapm.jpg)

The problem of the col-sm-3: [Problem of col-sm-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VkGg.png)

This is the code of the displaying of my card:

```css
.vehicule-card {
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: solid 4px #2F3136;
    background-color: #333333;
}

.vehicule-cardbody {
    height: 5em;
}

.vehicule-name {
    background-color: #392A49;
    color: #B8BABD;
    width: 10em;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 3px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: solid 4px #2F3136;
}

.vehicule-image {
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: solid 4px #2F3136;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="headline">VOITURES COMPACTS</div>
        <div class="row">
            @foreach (var car in Model.cars)
            {
                if (counter != 0 && counter % 4 == 0)
                {
                @:</div>
                @:<div class="row">
                }

                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                     <div class="card p-3 m-2 box-shadow vehicule-card">
                      <img class="card-img-top vehicule-image" src="@car.ImgPath" alt="Card image cap">
                            <div class="card-body vehicule-cardbody">
                                <h2 class="vehicule-name">@car.Name</h2>
                            </div>
                     </div>
                    </div>

                counter++;
            }

        </div>




    </div>
```

Don't try running the code, it will not work because it's a razor view.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the layout you want using Bootstrap’s [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/card/#grid-cards).

Your image for the layout you want is larger than what Bootstrap-4 provides with the container-xl (Bootstap-5 has a container-xxl), but you can create your own xxl container (my example has the max width at 1440px, but you can change that).

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<style>
body {
    background-color: #212121;
    color: #fff;
}

h1 {
    color: #B8BABD;
}

hr {
    width: 10%;
    border-top: 5px solid #392A49;
} 

.container-xxl {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

@media (min-width:1500px) {
    .container-xxl {
        max-width: 1440px;

    }
}

.vehicule-card {
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: solid 4px #2F3136;
    background-color: #333333;
}

.vehicule-cardbody {
    height: 5em;
}

.vehicule-name {
    background-color: #392A49;
    color: #B8BABD;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: solid 4px #2F3136;
}

.vehicule-image {
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: solid 4px #2F3136;
}
</style>

<div class="container-xxl">
    <h1 class="text-center mt-5">VOITURES COMPACTS</h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-lg-4">
        <div class="col mb-3">
            <div class="card p-3 m-2 box-shadow vehicule-card">
                <img class="card-img-top vehicule-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/192x108/FF8F8F/000000.png?text=Blista" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body px-0 vehicule-cardbody">
                    <h2 class="vehicule-name">Blista</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-3">
            <div class="card p-3 m-2 box-shadow vehicule-card">
                <img class="card-img-top vehicule-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/192x108/FFEE8F/000000.png?text=Dilettante" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body px-0 vehicule-cardbody">
                    <h2 class="vehicule-name">Dilettante</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-3">
            <div class="card p-3 m-2 box-shadow vehicule-card">
                <img class="card-img-top vehicule-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/192x108/B0FF8F/000000.png?text=Issi" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body px-0 vehicule-cardbody">
                    <h2 class="vehicule-name">Issi</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-3">
            <div class="card p-3 m-2 box-shadow vehicule-card">
                <img class="card-img-top vehicule-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/192x108/8FD2FF/000000.png?text=Panto" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body px-0 vehicule-cardbody">
                    <h2 class="vehicule-name">Panto</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-3">
            <div class="card p-3 m-2 box-shadow vehicule-card">
                <img class="card-img-top vehicule-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/192x108/AB8FFF/000000.png?text=Prairie" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body px-0 vehicule-cardbody">
                    <h2 class="vehicule-name">Prairie</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-3">
            <div class="card p-3 m-2 box-shadow vehicule-card">
                <img class="card-img-top vehicule-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/192x108/FF8FF4/000000.png?text=Rhapsody" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body px-0 vehicule-cardbody">
                    <h2 class="vehicule-name">Rhapsody</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My example code is in plain HTML, but you should be able to reverse it to work with Razor.

Comment: I don't know Grand Theft Auto, but I do know wide-screen monitors.